# SQL Server : I am trying to add a conditional select of column values based on another column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, filter, row-number

Here is my example table:

```
CREATE TABLE demo1 
(
    ProviderID int NOT NULL,
    ProviderClientID int NOT NULL,
    ClientIdentifier nvarchar(9) NOT NULL,
    ClientIdentifierTypeID int NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO demo1 (ProviderID, ProviderClientID, ClientIdentifier, ClientIdentifierTypeID)
VALUES 
(5, 7, 123444567, 1),
(5, 7, 000111234, 2),
(5, 11, 145342332, 1),
(5, 12, 234212345, 1),
(5, 13, 324564332, 3),
(5, 14, 123222467, 3),
(5, 19, 234444879, 1),
(5, 19, 000111643, 2),
(5, 19, 999234252, 3),
(5, 20, 456333245, 1)
```

The column `ClientIdentifierTypeID` values mean:

```
1 - Drivers License #,
2 - SchoolID,
3 - StateID
```

So clients can be in the table multiple times with different identifier types.

I want to select each client & just their drivers license #. If they don't have drivers license, then get their state id. I don't want their school id at all.

This is going to be part of a client count I am going to do next.

Here is what I tried in my query so far (I filter out school id already):

```
WITH A AS
(
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        demo1
    WHERE
        ClientIdentifierTypeID IN ('1', '3')
), B AS
(
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [ProviderClientID] ORDER BY [ClientIdentifierTypeID]) AS rn
    FROM 
        A
)
SELECT
    *
FROM 
    B
WHERE 
    rn = 1
```

EDIT: I am re-reading through my query, it seems do what I want.
When there is a license# rn will be 1. If no license, the state id will have rn=1.

Comment: and your question is...

Comment: `I want to select each client & just their drivers license #. If they don't have drivers license, then get their state id. ` -- Try a CASE WHEN statement.

Comment: So what doesn't work about your current query? (Must say it looks verbose, you can merge `B` into `A`)

Comment: Given the data you provided this query seems to work as expected.  What is the problem?

Comment: @JMabee I am going to edit my post

Comment: Why are you using tow CTEs for this. If you know the Execution order, you can perfrom this at once. But I am not sure about what you need?
select * from 
(
    SELECT
        *
  ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [ProviderClientID] ORDER BY [ClientIdentifierTypeID]) AS rn
    FROM
        demo1
    WHERE
        ClientIdentifierTypeID IN ('1', '3')
) as B where B.rn = 1

Answer (score 1):

If counts clients including school id then disable where clause otherwise enable it.

```
-- sql server
SELECT ProviderClientID
     , COUNT(1) count_client
     , MIN(CASE WHEN ClientIdentifierTypeID = 1
                   THEN ClientIdentifier
                WHEN ClientIdentifierTypeID = 3
                   THEN ClientIdentifier
           END)
FROM demo1
-- WHERE ClientIdentifierTypeID IN ('1', '3')
GROUP BY ProviderClientID;
```

Answer (score 1):

I use two Selects to filter. One is to get the uses who has driver  License . Second block is to get the users who has Sate but not driver license.
then combine both lists with UNION ALL.
This is one possibility.

```
 --client has driver License 
  SELECT * FROM  demo1
  WHERE ClientIdentifierTypeID  in (1)
  AND ClientIdentifierTypeID not in  (3,2)

  UNION ALL

  -- Clients who has State and not driver License 
 SELECT * FROM  demo1
 WHERE  ClientIdentifierTypeID  in (3)
 and ProviderClientID Not in (SELECT ProviderClientID FROM  demo1
 WHERE ClientIdentifierTypeID  in (1)
   )
```

[image: Result]